# Not able to upgrade termcolor to 1.1.0, because of which Tensorflow is failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, termcolor

I have been trying to install tensorflow, and getting this below error

```
ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies

  Using cached gast-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
Collecting tensorboard<1.15.0,>=1.14.0
  Using cached tensorboard-1.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.1 MB)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<1.15.0rc0,>=1.14.0rc0
  Using cached tensorflow_estimator-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (488 kB)
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached tensorflow-1.13.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (63.1 MB)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<1.14.0rc0,>=1.13.0
  Using cached tensorflow_estimator-1.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (367 kB)
Collecting tensorflow
  Using cached tensorflow-1.13.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (63.1 MB)

The conflict is caused by:
    tensorflow 2.4.1 depends on termcolor~=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.4.0 depends on termcolor~=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.3.2 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.3.1 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.3.0 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.2.2 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.2.1 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.2.0 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.1.3 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.1.2 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.1.1 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.1.0 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.0.4 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.0.3 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.0.2 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.0.1 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 2.0.0 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 1.15.5 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 1.15.4 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 1.15.3 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 1.15.2 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 1.15.0 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 1.14.0 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 1.13.2 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0
    tensorflow 1.13.1 depends on termcolor>=1.1.0

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

Upon digging further, I checked that termcolor is already installed correctly, as I am able to import it properly, but it is possible that my termcolor version is a lower version.

But again, i am not able to find which version of termcolor do i have.

Anybody has any idea how to upgrade termcolor to 1.1.0, probably if we can do that, tensorflow installation would be successful.

**

> Sorry for the long post

**

Comment: `Termcolor` gets installed itself when you install `tensorflow`. How are you trying to install `tensorflow` and which platform, OS are you using? Also let us know which `python` version have you installed in your system.